# Removing loss of significance

Tags: numerical-methods

I am given $f(x) = 1 + x - \frac{sin(x)}{(x e^x)} $ and am asked to solve this for when x ≃ 0.

I'm doing the following steps but am getting stuck halfway through:

$$f(x) = 1 + x - \frac {x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}}{xe^x} $$

$$= 1 + x - \frac{e^{-x} (x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120})}{x} $$

$$= 1 + x - \frac {(1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}) (x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120})}{x} $$

At this point however I'm not really sure what I should be doing next. I figure that multiplying the numerator part is not necessary, so I don't see what else to do. Could someone provide me with a hint on how to finish this?

Comment: $\frac{\sin(x)}{x e^x} \approx \frac{x}{x}=1$.

Comment: How are you getting $xe^x$ to be equivalent to sin?

Comment: $\sin(x) \approx x$ and $e^{x} \approx 1$.

Comment: you can get rid of the $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: except if you're taking sin(x) for when it is close to 0 to get 1, then when you do the same for the denominator, won't you end up with $0 * 1$ hence $\frac{1}{1*0}$ I'm slightly confused

Answer (score 1):

Since in a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+o(x^2),\qquad e^{-x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$
it happens that:
$$\frac{\sin x}{x e^x}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{3}+o(x^2) $$
so:
$$ f(x) = 1+x-\frac{\sin x}{x e^x}\approx 2x-\frac{x^2}{3}$$
and provided that $g(x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$,
$$ g(x)\approx \frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{24}. $$

Comment: How are you getting g(x)? Everything else makes sense in your explanation

Comment: @Valrok: series inversion. Since you know the derivatives of $f$ in $0$, you also know the derivatives of $g$, and by computing them you get the last formula. As an alternative, you can use undeterminate coefficients and find them by imposing that in a neighbourhood of zero $f(g(x))=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$
You have 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{xe^x}=1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(1+x-\dfrac{\sin x}{xe^x}\right)=1+0-1=0
$$
so, for $x \simeq 0 $ you have $f(x)<\epsilon \qquad\forall \epsilon>0$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you DO need to expand the numerator. But you only need terms up to x^3 in both factors.

Comment: Why only up to $x^3$? An explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i will take it from your last step.
$\begin{align} 1 + x - \frac{e^{-x} \sin x}{x} &= 1 + x - 
\left(1 - \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots \right)
\left( 1 -  \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} + \cdots\right)\\
&=1 + x - 
\left(1 - x + x^2(\frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!}) + \cdots \right)\\
&= 2x - \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \cdots
\end{align}$